# C# Accessing Mix Content received from [from body] x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, class, json.net

I have set a WebHook and i am receiving a mixed Content, which after Url Decoding, this is what i get:

```
chat_id=222231&from={"id":201232,"name":"John","user":"User_Admin"}&type=text&data=yes
```

i Serialized it like so:

```
 var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                                                 encode.Keys.Cast<string>()
                                                     .ToDictionary(k => k, k => encode[k]));
```

then when using:

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(json.ToString());
```

i get:

```
{
  "chat_id": "222231",
  "from": "\"{\"id\":201232,\"name\":\"John\",\"user\":\"User_Admin\"}\"",
  "type": "text",
  "data": "yes"
}
```

Well, i could access "from" by parsing it, but shouldn't there be a better way to do this !!? if creating a class will do it then how does it look !!? because no matter how i did it, it just returned null for the "form"

Comment: you must create a class that contains `chat_id` as int or int64, `type` as string , `data` as string, and `from` as from class. therefore you must have 2 class. one is main class and second is from class. then use something like `JObject.Parse<MainClass>(json.ToString());` .

Comment: @HosseinBadrnezhad i wish it was that simple :) i have tried that but it only returnes null for the "form"

Comment: do you try deserialize your object with “Newton Soft” from nuget?

Comment: @HosseinBadrnezhad i am using newton the problem is how to construct the class